# p:inputNumber range restriction

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces - inputNumber range restriction not working when setting between 100 and 200. But works between 1 to 200.

```
<p:inputNumber id="decidedRatio" value="#{remunerationBean.model.decidedRatio}" minValue="100" maxValue="200" symbol=" %" symbolPosition="s"
        emptyValue="sign" decimalPlaces="0" styleClass="field" required="#{!remunerationBean.fromAuthorisationPage}">
</p:inputNumber>
```

**Update:-**

It does not even allow to start typing any number, may be the minimum it would allow is 100 straight away and does not allow to type that 100 by 1 0 0. Sounds odd though

Comment: what "not working" means ?

Comment: Did you debug the js code of this component to see if it contains an explanation? The code **is** open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it works.

The typed number is not accepted if the resulting value in the field is not in the range.  In an empty field when you type "1" the resulting value is "1" and it is out of your range (100 to 200).

IMHO, this is just too much invasive client side validation.  I suggest to allow 0 to 999 and server validate that it is between 100 and 200.